# Regular Expression In Oracle ADF

Tags: java, regex, oracle, oracle-adf

I am using Regular Expression to allow all the Special Characters along with Numbers and alphabets in java based ORACLE ADF.
Following is my Regular Expression:

```
regExVal="^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()-+=~!_]+$";
```

But I am getting error,If i am adding `!` or `_` characters. The rest works.

Comment: Note you need to put the `-` at the start/end of the pattern, or escape it.

Comment: Example Please@Wiktor Stribizew

Comment: Your current regex does not match a string containing `-` because `[)-+]` matches `)`, `*` and `+` - that part should be fixed with `regExVal="^[-a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()+=~!_]+$";`

Comment: With the Following regEx ,It is working for  _ but not working for !                                                               
      regExVal="^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()_+=~-]+$";@Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Which error are you getting exactly ? 
Probably the script is breaking cause ADF is generated somewhere an xml so to have some characters managed properly you need to encode them in html-like notation, i.e. &amp instead of & and &#33&#95 instead of !_

Comment: You must be able to use `regExVal="^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()_+=~-]+$";`. It is not a Bash environment, right? If it is, you need to escape the `!` symbol or use single quotes, `regExVal='^[!a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()_+=~-]+$';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex does not match a string containing `-` because `[)-+]` matches `)`, `*` and `+`. The double quoted string literal seems to be the culprit, too.

You need to define the pattern inside single quotes and put the hyphen at the end of the character class:

```
regExVal='^[!a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*()_+=~-]+$';
                                   ^^
```